# MQ connecting with SSL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ibm-mq

I have to connect to IBM MQ using C# in .NET 4.0 using SSL. I have the 4 file of the key and also the .TAB file. But I also know the channel details.
Can someone provide me with a clear example ?
Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

From the mention of .TAB in your question, I am assuming that you are asking how to set up SSL using the Client Channel Definition Table (CCDT) which is often a file called AMQCLCHL.TAB. The knowledge center contains information about how to do this in this page:-

[Using a client channel definition table with .NET](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029600_.htm)

There are some differences depending on whether you are using unmanaged .NET or fully managed .NET. If the latter, please also read:-

[CipherSpec support for the managed .NET client](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120610_.htm)

specifcally the very last sub-section about CCDT usage.

Comment: Do you require sample code for making a connection to MQ using .NET or for using the CCDT?